Python SSH Paramiko set_keepalive not working on Linux
I'm trying to write a script that initializes firmware upgrade of the network switch and analyzes the output from the switch once SSH session is terminated.
I use Python 3.11 an Paramiko 3.4.0.
To make SSH session get terminated and code execution move on, I set set_keepalive timeout, e.g:
transport = client.get_transport()
transport.set_keepalive(10)

When this code is executed on Windows, it works as expected. Once switch reboots, Paramiko's SSH session terminates almost instantly (so 10 second keepalive timeout is honored  - no keepalives for 10 seconds so session gets terminated), my code moves on and I'm able to parse the output returned from the SSH session.
This does not work well on Linux (RHEL) though. Even though switch reboots, Paramiko SSH session does not instantly disconnect from it. It takes 5 or more minutes to detect that SSH session died and I get errors like "socket exeption, reset by peer" then. Network switch has already rebooted by this time.
Unfortunately in production I have to run this script on Linux.
I tried to use Paramiko exec_command timeout instead. But this does not work well either because I cannot really predict how log the upgrade is going to take. Setting to too high value means that it disconnects after the switch came up already (so no improvement).
Too low - session gets disconnected with error even though switch hasn't rebooted yet.
It does look like Paramiko issue not honoring set_keepalive on Linux, no idea why.
When I use 'generic' ssh command on Linux (outside of Python/Paramiko) with -o ServerAliveInterval=10 to connect to the switch and initiate firmware upgrade, then it works as expected, as Paramiko in Windows would - it disconnects promptly after switch stops responding.
No idea how to fix it.

After some more research and testing. Call it post-mortem.
Literally you are right that ServerAliveCountMax is what makes stale connection to be dropped by OpenSSH client when there are no keepalive responses from server.
There is no such option possible in Paramiko though. set_keepalive only replicates ServerAliveInterval.
When I lauch switch upgrade on Linux/RHEL from ssh with no options, e.g:
ssh user@switch "<NX-OS upgrade command>"

it effecitvely hangs when switch reboot. There is no traffic between client and server and no way to detect stale connection. It terminates only after I press Enter to send some packets to server.
But that's not what's happening in my Python script when Paramiko is used without set_keepalive - there's no one to press Enter in the script and make some traffic in exec_command after switch had rebooted so exec_command hangs forever waiting for command execution to complete.
If I do this in Linux instead:
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=10 user@switch "<NX-OS upgrade command>"

then it's better. Connection is not dropped immediately - it takes a minute or so but eventually command auto-terminates and prompt is returned. Just becuase there's some traffic in the seesion (SSH keepalives) and it helps TCP stack (?) detect stale TCP connection and drop it.
Same happens in Paramiko with set_keepalive(10) - exec_command eventually terminates but how long it takes seems to be platform-dependent, like with SSH (Windows - very quick, Linux - up to 5 mins as per my observations.)
Eventually this works best on Linux:
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=10 -o ServerAliveCountMax=2 user@switch "<NX-OS upgrade command>"

Session gets terminated very quickly. The problem is that it cannot be replicated with Paramiko - no ServerAliveCountMax equivalent there.
I think I need to make an enhancement request to Paramiko :-)
The other option I have (difficult) is to write code that uses Paramiko channels and live analyze output sent by switch - close SSH session myself once the message confirming beginning switch reboot is returned, wothout waiting for underlying OS to terminate dead connection.
Or live with it.
I tried to use exec_command's timeout instead but it is useless - if exec_command times out, it throws and exception (good) but stdout and stderr returned by it are empty (bad) so I do not know what really happened in the switch - whether switch upgrade started and switch rebooted or whether switch refused to be upgraded and upgrade command terminated.
Also setting correct timeout is difficult. Switch being upgraded does not send frequent responses - sometimes it stays silent for two minutes before giving more output from next upgrade steps. So too short value triggers timeout when switch is still moving on upgrade steps, too high - causes delay with reboot detection at the end.
Background:
I'm developing a tool to faciliate NX-OS upgrades on CISCO MDS switches for the company I work for.
Initially I was using Python 2.7 and calling external process (ssh via Popen) to connect to switches. At that time Python 3.x and Paramiko were not "allowed/approved to use" here.
But it was a tool for pre/post-upgrade checks only, not for actual upgrades. By calling ssh using Popen I was limited to key-based authentication and the only account I was able to authenticate on switches was read-only (it was sufficent for prechecks) so it did work for me.
To perform actual upgrades I needed to authenticate with user/password - I could not use external SSH for this. So had to wait for Python 3.x and Paramiko to "get certified" or approved to use.
Once it happened I was able to start working on implementing upgrades in my tool but then I encoutered these challenges.
Hope it helps someone in the future.
